# Espaçamento em branco não sai do documento html

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, materialize

Bem, já procurei várias soluções como: `*,html{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}` / `body, html{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}`, mas nenhuma resolveu a solução do espaçamento em branco na página, segue o código

**Segue o html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">

      <!-- Import style.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 l4 card-panel black first_panel">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 l4 card-panel indigo lighten-1 second_panel">
        </div>
        <div class="col s4 l4 card-panel light-blue lighten-1 third_panel">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6 l4  card-panel black first_panel">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 l4  card-panel indigo lighten-1 second_panel">
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 l4  card-panel light-blue lighten-1 third_panel">
        </div>
      </div>





      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**E o css também:**

```
     *, html {
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
     }


    .first_panel{
        height: 50vh;
     }

    .second_panel{
       height: 50vh;
     }

    .third_panel{
       height: 50vh;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta tirar o bootstrap (para ver se é ele quem está mudando), independente do resultado tente colocar no body `margin:0 !important;`

Comment: Consegui resolver

Answer (score 0):

Vc diz o espaço em branco que fica entre o conteúdo e a borda do documento?

Se for isso utilize apenas o `body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Particularmente não sou fã de dar um reset de margin e padding em todos os elementos.